# Haw to map through all the names in this array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList, SectionList} from 'react-native';
import { Item, Input,  Container, Header, List, ListItem, Text, Left, Right, Icon } from "native-base";

const NigLawList= ({navigation}) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
      {Law: "Evidence Act", id: "1",
      part:[ {name: "Introduction 1", meaning: "how are you doing"},
      {name: "Introduction 2", meaning: "how are you doing"}
      
    ]},

])
  
    return (
      <FlatList
      numColumns={1}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
      data={people} 
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <List >

          <ListItem onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NigLawParts', item)}>
           
              <Text  style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            }}>{item.Law}</Text>
             
          </ListItem>

          </List>
      )}





      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />

    );
  }
  
  export default NigLawList;
```

Please how can i map through all the "names" in this array in a react native flatlist. I simply want to display the "name" which is under part. please i really need help with this! i am new to react native.

Comment: Please consider formatting your source code and correct the typos in your question.

Comment: Where do you want to show the names? inside the same list item or should it be a separate list? your requirement is not clear

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to show it in the same list. Please forgive me.. I am new to react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can render the contents of the `Law` key as well as corresponding names from the `part` array.

I Have omitted the `List` and `ListItem` component.

Code:

```
const NigLawList = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
    {
      Law: "Evidence Act",
      id: "1",
      part: [
        { name: "Introduction cc", meaning: "how are you don" },
        { name: "Introduction bb", meaning: "how are you don" },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={people}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 20,
              }}
            >
              {item.Law}
            </Text>
            {item.part.map((name) => (
              <Text>{name.name}</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default NigLawList;
```

Also do read docs for more info: [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

Output:

[image]

Code for Navigating to next screen with parameters:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const NigLawList = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
    {
      Law: "Evidence Act",
      id: "1",
      part: [
        { name: "Introduction cc", meaning: "how are you don" },
        { name: "Introduction bb", meaning: "how are you don" },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={people}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Names", { parts: item.part })}
          >
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 20,
                }}
              >
                {item.Law}
              </Text>
              {/* {item.part.map((name) => (
                <Text>{name.name}</Text>
              ))} */}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const NamesScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { parts } = route.params;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      {parts.map((part) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={part.name}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("Meaning", { meaning: part.meaning })
          }
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
            }}
          >
            {part.name}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const MeaningScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const { meaning } = route.params;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          marginTop: 20,
        }}
      >
        {meaning}
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="NigLawList" component={NigLawList} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Names" component={NamesScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Meaning" component={MeaningScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Kentan! Can you please help me out. How can i pass "names" in a new screen and show it in another flatlist in that screen.

Comment: I have been able to pass names to another screen to another screen but i can display them in a new list.

Comment: Right now I am away from my laptop so couldn't send the working code , will post it once I get back home. Meanwhile go through this docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: I hope you implemented navigation with parameter passing, if you haven't already then do check out the updated code.

Comment: This works fine Sir. But there is a little problem. The names are displaying in one line over here. I does not display as a list.

Comment: are you referring to code in the answer or your own?

Comment: Sir can i also pass "meaning" to another screen? If yes, Please help me out. I promise to buy you coffee. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: no need to pass ```meaning``` separately, you can access it by ```{ parts: item.part }``` parameter that we are passing while navigating from ```NigLawList ```. Just access it by ```name.meaning``` like this: ```{parts.map((name) => ( <Text key={name.meaning}>{name.meaning}</Text>))}```. Just like we did with name

Comment: That is correct sir. But i want to hard code some data into the array. So i need to pass it to another screen from "name" to allow the users access "meaning" of every "name' easily.

Comment: Not sure if I am getting correctly, but I assume you are trying to make ```name``` clickable, and when that name is clicked then the user needs to be sent to another screen showing ```meaning``` of the corresponding name, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes sir. That is what i want to achieve

Comment: like this? : https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-7-56086ba4a629.gif

Comment: This is exactly what i want to achieve sir.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I cant thank you enough. You deserve something sir. Please send me any means i can at least buy you a coffee...

Answer (score 0):

Below is a short screen of how the list is in my emulator
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fwlc.png)

Comment: to get rid of that two ```names``` in one line remove outer ```<Text>``` component and keep only ```{parts.map((name) => (
        <Text key={name.name}>{name.name}</Text>
      ))}``` in that container